# Delay issue in time series prediction

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I am having an issue using neural networks to predict time series. Some predicted data fits with the expected data, as bellow: (In black the real time series and in blue the output of my neural network)

[image: Australia energy demand]
*Time serie: Australia energy demand.*

But with the same code, with other time series, the predicted data does not fits with the expected data, and has a delay of one unit, as bellow:

[image]
*Time serie: Walmart Stock price.*
[image]
*Time serie: Dollar libra exchange.*

I found some articles about some variations of neural networks and at the results section shows the plot with the delay like my results, as bellow:

[image]
*Time serie: Dollar libra exchange. 
(Article link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915015793)*

Anyone knows if this is a common behavior or can be something wrong with my code ? I am having this issue about three months ago, and since there I am trying to figure out some bug in my code but is all right.

Thanks and I appreciate any tip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about digital signal processing in general, not programming. try dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is not about digital signal processing. Is about Time series prediction using neural network.

Comment: um, you've got an estimator for a discrete quantity that exists for discrete times. That's an estimator a digital signal. That's DSP.

Comment: nnets can be implemented in many different ways, with a whole host of possible parameters. you're asking us to diagnose a black box w/o any context at all other than some result plots.

Comment: @hiandbaii is right. This is like asking someone to describe the taste of the color blue who's blind, but once was explained how red strawberries taste like.

Comment: @hiandbaii I am using Extreme Learning Machine. The source code is [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/elm_codes.html)

Comment: Are you using a validation dataset?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I am splitting the data in two: Trainning (first 70%) and Test(the last 30% ).

Comment: @ViniciusArruda. I have same problem when using SVR in matlab. any clue?

Comment: @user2991243 I found many articles that concludes this behavior as the random walk. I asked this same question at [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197494/delay-issue-in-time-series-prediction)

Comment: @MarcusMüller 1. [It's NOT about digital signal processing](https://www.quora.com/How-was-signal-processing-analysis-different-than-time-series-analysis), it's about time series prediction. 2. This is an incredibly unique, well written question (and still is 8 years later...); even if it wasn't technically in the proper forum, that'd be very bad taste closing it. Go bother the Python noobs on here if you want to play SO whackamole instead of actually answering questions.

Comment: @KrustytheClown 8 years later, indeed :) But: time series prediction *is* signal processing. We do that all the time; in fact, *linear predictive coding* is one of the most-used techniques in audio processing / compression. I think I'm a bit more of an authority on that than some quora user calling themselves "Machine Learning Beginner" ;) No matter whether you want to call it signal processing or not, nothing here is a programming question, and hence, this remains off-topic, 8 years later. Let me re-vote to close it, now that we have the "not about programming" close reason.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fine, would you rather listen to an [MBA in finance who's answer got upvoted by a CS & Data Mining PHD?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-differences-and-similarities-between-digital-signal-processing-and-time-series-analysis) Or if you prefer something closer to home, how about this [CrossValidated post?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52270/relations-and-differences-between-time-series-analysis-and-statistical-signal-pr) Just because they're similar, doesn't mean they're the same. You're just wasting the mods' time.

Comment: @KrustytheClown no, thanks, that's too much stuff to read from people that all agree with me: this is not a programming but a signals/data theory/statistics/prediction problem and hence should not be posted here :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller  "But: time series prediction is signal processing." (Marcus Müller). "On the other hand, DSP usually deals with only a single signal at a time, whereas TSA often relates multiple series and can involve many covariates." (Aaron Brown, Quora). "while there are major overlaps, the differences between signal processing and time-series analysis often arise from the types of data being considered;" (BGreene). I can assure you they do not agree with you dude. Once again, similar does not mean the same.

Comment: @KrustytheClown I don't *care* whether you want to call this DSP or something else. It's **not a programming question**, and **that** is the criterion for it being off-topic here. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had a problem like this. The answer was simply that the model was not good enough. Qualitatively, the model is predicting that your next output will be very similar to the previous one, so the output appears to be delayed by one. Improve your model (different type of net, number of hidden layers, feedback, etc), and the predictions will improve, and the appearance of off-by-one will disappear.

Comment: The algorithm that I am using (ELM) usually has one hidden layer and I am using just one. An example that I has this lag behavior with 10 neurons in the hidden layer and the Trainning and Testing set is with this lag. If I change to 1000 neurons, the Trainning set is perfectly, with almost zero error, but the Testing set has bigger error than when was 10 neurons. So, with 1000 neuros the model is really good for the trainning, but is terrible for the testing set.

Comment: Just to complement, with 1000 neurons in the hidden layer the model is overfitting, and with 10 neurons, the model, like you said, is not good enough.

Comment: Right, so it seems like the answer is correct- you need to improve the model :) I suggest you mark this answer as correct, and start a new question with specific details about your model and the problems you are encountering with it, and the methods you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I have three main parameters, if you see the article I quoted, the parameters are mu, tau and the number of neurons in the hidden layer. I do not want to grow my number of neurons, so I will change just the mu and tau.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering if anyone knows, would this be considered a type of overfitting? And is there any special term for when the model's predictions are delayed by a timestep like this?